# Failed to get the response in Swagger 3 (open api) while using Java 19 and Spring Boot 3.0.x

Tags: spring-boot, response, springdoc-openapi-ui, swagger-3.0, java-19

I'm migrating from Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3 with Java 19 and also using swagger 3 that's open api.

I have added the "open api webmvc ui" dependency in POM file and also changed Javax to Jakarta. I have configured in open api configure file. And disabled the Spring Fox dependency as well. In controller class also, I have added @operation and @ api response annotations.

I don't know what I'm missing. Swagger 3 is able to launch and give the inputs, but when I click execute, I always get bad request or any other errors. I am unable to test the API. I also tried in postman as well the same error occurred.

May be I missed something to accept the inputs from Swagger 3 (open api), but I don't know where it is.

When I tried the open api with Spring Boot 2 and Java 8, it is working fine for me.